# How to pause an m4b file

Tags: itunes, playback, m4a

When I play m4b files on my computer, they open with iTunes.  I can stop the file, but I cannot resume the file from within iTunes.  In order to pick up where I left off, I have to open the file again.

How can I resume where I left off from within iTunes?  Is there another program that will play m4b files and resume from where you left off?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can stop the file"? If you open the m4b file in itunes, it should be added to your library as a regular track. When you pause it, it should resume playback from where you left off if you press play again.

Answer (score 1):

When you have imported a track into your iTunes library (it doesn't matter which type), choose **Get Info** on that track, then go to **Options** and check **Remember playback position**

This will allow you to resume playback within iTunes.